# Get the thread state stated from another class

Tags: python, multithreading

Let's say I have the following code (`start.py`) that starts a thread and never exits (Note: don't mind the typos or lack of some code lines, just get the idea.):

```
from threading import Thread
from anApp import AnApp

class ClassA(Thread):
    def __init__(self, _parent):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.parent = _parent

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            self.parent.anApp.execute()

            # Here, I want to known if the thread started in appX.py is alive.
            # if the thread stated by appX.py is alive:
            #     print 'App x is running'
            # else:
            #     print 'App x is not running'

class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.th = None
        self.anApp = AnApp()

    def someFunction(self):
        self.th = ClassA(self)
        self.th.start()
```

Now, `anApp.py` looks something like this:

```
from appX import App

Class AnApp():
    # def __init__(self) goes here...

    def execute(self):
        self.appX = App()
        self.appX.startRunning()
```

Finally, `appX.py` looka something like this (similar to `start.py`):

```
from threading import Thread

class ClassX(Thread):
    def __init__(self, _parent):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.parent = _parent

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            print 'Im here!!!'

class App():
    # def __init__(self) goes here....

    def startRunning(self):
        self.listen = ClassX(self)
        self.listen.start()
```

I want to know if the thread started by `startRunning` in `appX.py` is alive, in `start.py` (check the comments I wrote above).

Comment: Your code doesn't match the calls you're making. There is no `App` class in `appX.py`, for example, but you're doing this: `from appX import App`

Comment: you're right @dano. I missed a function in `appX.py`. I updated the post.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured you meant, and what the answer I gave assumed, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want this, though your sample code seems to be inconsistent in some areas, so I can't be 100% sure this will work with your real code:

```
def run(self):
    while 1:
        self.parent.anApp.execute()  # Do you really want this inside the infinite loop?

        if self.parent.anApp.appX.listen.is_alive():
             print 'App x is running'
        else:
             print 'App x is not running'
```

This is assuming `appX.py` really looks like this:

```
from threading import Thread

class ClassX(Thread):
    def __init__(self, _parent):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.parent = _parent

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            print 'Im here!!!'

class App():
    # def __init__(self) goes here....
    def startRunning(self):
        self.listen = ClassX(self)
        self.listen.start()
```